# Does Laravel have a convention for organizing routes in routes.php?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I was contributing to a project that now has a routes.php file with like over 800 lines of routes. I was wondering if Laravel had a specific convention or a way to organize this so it doesn't have to have all routes in one large confusing file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best ways are groups and don't list every single route but use controller routes.
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-groups
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#implicit-controllers

If this doesn't help it's possible to split this file into multiple files, for example: routes/users.php, routes/posts.php and so on, and include these into the original routes.php

Answer (score 4):

Separate routes for large applications into multiple smaller route partial files that are automatically loaded at runtime.

Also you can

1. [Group routes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-groups)
2. [Route namespaces](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-group-namespaces)
3. [Route prefixes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-group-prefixes)

**Useful examples**

[partial routes](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/organize-routes-with-route-partials)

[split routes in different parts](http://laravelsnippets.com/snippets/split-routes-into-different-files)

[organize routes](http://ryantablada.com/post/organizing-routes-in-laravel-4)

[explained route using](http://ollieread.com/blog/2014/08/17/laravel-routes-like-a-grown-up/)

[break routes](https://laravel-news.com/2014/04/laravel-tip-break-up-your-routes/)

Also i can recommend route caching for performance

[Route caching tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/8)

Answer (score 0):

Also it would help to put some routes in different files. 
For example, you could create a folder called routes in your app folder, then add files in that folder. I usually have one file for authentication routes, then other files for the high level navigation items of the site.

don't forget to require those files in app/start/global.php

```
/*
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | in app/start/global.php
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 */

require app_path( 'routes/auth.php'); // Auth routes
require app_path( 'routes/articles.php'); // Article routes
```

maybe you should also consider using controller along side this technique to further slim you routes

Comment: You can put the path directly into the app_path() function like all other laravel path helpers: `app_path('routes/auth.php')`

Comment: laravel 5.1 and up users should use RouteServiceProvider map function